# input command 'rake test',but can not get a response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake

[image]

I want to make a test in my project,but when I input command 'rake test', I can not get any response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2.0 minitest-rails does not add minitest rake tasks. The default rails test rake tasks are used. See the section on running tests in the README.

Also, if you are including the minitest-rails Railtie in your config/application.rb, then you shouldn't place the dependency in the :test group in your Gemfile.